Why do I get a Pyspark Runtime Error with SQL in Quiver?
Some context: Writing a custom expression with SQL on a data set I have in Quiver. Am getting an error that I quite frankly do not understand. I have tried casting the types to makes sure everything is of a common type but it doesn't seem to work. Not the most versed in java. Can you tell me where I should be looking, is it a stupid error cuased by my sql code, is my data set not compatible?

Error: org.apache.spark.SparkRuntimeException:
[UNSUPPORTED_FEATURE.LITERAL_TYPE] The feature is not supported:
Literal for '{type= concrete, value = 72130}' of class
java.util.LinkedHashMap.

Have tried casting and changing the data types to characters, but it doesn't seem to have an effect.
